# Can Google Analytics track video with tracking parameters?

Tags: youtube, google-analytics, tracking

If I link my Google Analytics ID to my YouTube channel, would individual videos be able to tracked via parameters? For example, if one clicks on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMPzDiraNnA&utm_source=test%20source&utm_medium=test%20medium&utm_campaign=test%20name&utm_term=post%3A%20main, would Google Analytics track the click?

According to [How to Check if Google Analytics Is Installed Correctly](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/check-google-analytics-installed-correctly-49238.html), if there is `google-analytics` in the source code, then Google Analytics is installed. I check that in my video, and there is none. It's the same with my YouTube account page.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do that, you can use Youtube analytics, where you can get all of stuff you need. But all related to youtube, here is the official google link with overview and all helpful links you need to get started.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/92725?hl=en

Comment: but I need to know whether a link I post in a specific website is clicked how many times

Answer (score 0):

If you use utm parameters on a link, it will be tracked as a source in your Google Analytics  - you don't need to have the GA code on that source, in fact that just confuses matters. You can add a GA ID to your YouTube account, and that will track your page views in YouTube. It's not actually very useful, as the other comment said, YouTube analytics gives you a lot more data on how your YouTube videos are performing.